# SQL: How do I (or can I) select multiple columns and relate to another column

Tags: sql

I'm still a begginer with SQL, and I cannot find a way to accomplish the following.

In table A I have the following.

```
ID, Name
1, somethingGeeky
2, reallyGeeky
3, TotallyGeeky
```

In table B I use the uniqueID's to relate prerequisites.

```
Id, prerequisiteID
3, 2
2, 1
```

I'm trying to write a statement that will query Table B, but replace the unique ID's with the names from table A.

So, It'll display like..

```
Name, Prerequisite
TotallyGeeky, reallyGeeky
reallyGeekly, somethingGeeky
```

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1):

you need to join table `A` twice to table `B`.  First time for the first column and second time for the second:

```
select a1.name, a2.name
   from b
      inner join a a1
         b.id = a1.id
      inner join a a2
         b.prerequisiteID = a2.id
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT x.Name AS Name, y.Name AS Prerequisite FROM B
INNER JOIN A x ON B.ID = x.ID
INNER JOIN A y ON B.prerequisiteID = y.ID
```

Comment: Added column names as requested in the OP.

Comment: unless you just love typing, you can remove the `INNER`s - that is the default join type

Comment: Ya, inner might be redundant here, but still. Let's all just marvel in how much we love joins :)

Answer (score 1):

You just have to join the Relationship table with the Attributes table twice. Example below:

```
SELECT
  A1.Name
  ,A2.Name as PrerequisiteName
FROM
  RelationsTable R
  JOIN
  Attributes A1 ON
    (A1.Id = R.Id)
  JOIN
  Attributes A2 ON
    (A2.Id = R.PrerequisiteId)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
SELECT  a.Product_ID, b.brand_name
FROM    `product` a 
            INNER JOIN  `brand` b
                ON a.brand_id = b.brand_ID
```